# Vim: Align second set of opening quotes using Tabular

Tags: regex, vim, tabular

I've been using the excellent [Tabular](http://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin in Vim to align things, but there's an alignment I want to do pretty commonly that I can't figure out the right regex for.

I want this

```
gem 'fakeweb'
gem 'factory_girl', '~> 1.3'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 1.0'
gem 'rspec', '>= 2.0'
gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.0'
```

to turn into this

```
gem 'fakeweb'
gem 'factory_girl',       '~> 1.3'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '>= 1.0'
gem 'rspec',              '>= 2.0'
gem 'rspec-rails',        '>= 2.0'
```

The cheat would be to align it on the comma, but that's not my ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the \zs in your regex you can set the start of the match to be the quote and not the comma.

```
:%Tabularize /,\s*\zs'/
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone stumbling upon this question: `:Tabularize argument_list` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin.

Comment: That basically does the exact same thing as Tabular. Unless you had a regular expression to use with that I don't see your point.

Comment: I should had mention that \ts, have the same effect as the correct answer.

Comment: Yes it does the same thing easier: \ts, edit:sorry for the double comment (browser fault).